# how to get those 3 things working together: webpack, less and angular 2+?

Tags: angular, webpack, less

so I have 3 things: less style sheets, webpack, and angular 2+ in ts file.
Firstly I got it configured according to https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/165 
at first it works fine on my local environment but if I publish it onto a windows server, my someComp.component.less file is not working.

structure:

```
-client app
- - app
- - - components
- - - -someComponent
- - - - -someComp.component.html
- - - - -someComp.component.ts
- - - - -someComp.component.less
```

in my someComp.component.ts (and the in style it have an error called "the type of styles are incompatible" although in local dev environment it works fine.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'someComp',
    templateUrl: './someComp.component.html',
    styles: [require('./someComp.component.less')]
})
export class SomeCompComponent {
    //stuff...
}
```

in my webpack.config.js. I dont know how to config this thing.

```
const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.less', '.css', '.html'] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,
                    use: ????????????????????????????????? HOW TO CONFIG????
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin(), new ExtractTextPlugin('??????.css') //is this even necessary??]
    };
```

I just cannot get these 3 things working together. How to make these 3 things working together????? and if I publish those things onto a windows server, my less file stopped working. How???? how to get those work??????

Comment: how can you make webpack to work in the first place?

Comment: Just use Angular CLI, it'll make your life a lot less stressful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webpack + angular 2 + less gives me a lot of headaches. Developer should really deserve some better structures for these to work together but not spend 2 days on googling and tweaking with this freaking webpack.config.js

anyway.

I figured out you could do this

install less loader for webpack

```
npm install --save-dev less-loader less
```

then in my component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'someComp',
    templateUrl: './someComp.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./someComp.component.less'] <---here
})
export class someCompComponent {

}
```

then in my freaking webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { 
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.less', '.css', '.html'] <-----!!!!!!here
        },  
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,         <-----!!!!!!here
                    exclude: /node_modules/,  <-----!!!!!!here
                    loader: 'raw-loader!less-loader'   <-----!!!!!!here
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [...]
    };
```

well this works both on production and dev environment.